# Why is the "readinessState" detail of /health different from the readiness probe status?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-check, readinessprobe

In Spring-Boot 2.4, I have this problem with the Actuator health endpoint and readiness probe. When one of my custom key components is down, the `/health/readiness` endpoint says `DOWN` and the `/health` endpoint too, **but** the `readinessState` detail of `/health` still says `UP`.

**Why is it that way? Shouldn't `readinessState` say `DOWN` too?**

None of the many tutorials I found online seem to address this question.

My hypothesis: the `readinessState` has nothing to do with readiness and exposes another piece of information. I hope I'm wrong, because it would be nonesense and what I understand of [the code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.4.2/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/availability/ReadinessStateHealthIndicator.java#L35) seems to indicate otherwise.

---

More about my configuration:

Relevant excerpt from `application.yml`

```yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS
      probes:
        enabled: true
      group:
        readiness:
          include: db, myCustom, diskSpace
```

And when I make `myCustom` go `DOWN`, following results appear:

`GET /health`

```json
{
    "status": "DOWN",
    "components": {
        ...,  // other components
        "myCustom": {
            "status": "DOWN"
        },
        "readinessState": {
            "status": "UP"  // here UP
        }
    },
    "groups": [
        "liveness",
        "readiness"
    ]
}
```

`GET /health/readiness`

```json
{
    "status": "DOWN",  // but here DOWN
    "components": {
        ...,  // other components
        "myCustom": {
            "status": "DOWN"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The readiness state only monitors specific health groups. It needs to be told about your custom component.

> By default, Spring Boot does not add other Health Indicators to these groups.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-kubernetes-probes-external-state

Comment: Ok, so `readinessState` is just the "default" basic readiness information without dependencies? and I can include it in the readiness group with my custom checks to have the correct picture in the readiness probe?

Comment: By custom check, if you mean a health check that you implemented, then all you need is `management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=readinessState,customCheck`.